# Raw code works, doesn't if put in method?

Tags: ruby

In programming class, we are creating a program to translate a sentence to Pig Latin. We are specifically told to use methods, and one of the given ones for all assignments is that we could re-run it as many times as we want to. The normal code for the latter works in the sense that if we type `"no"`, it exits. However, if we put it in a method and call it at the end of the while loop, it acts as if we typed `"yes"`, with no regard to what we actually typed.

```
def ask_again()
    puts "Go again? "
    again = gets.chomp
    until again.downcase == "yes" || again.downcase == "no"
        puts "Please answer with \"Yes\" or \"No\""
        again = gets.chomp
    end
    if again == "yes"
        continue = true
    else
        continue = false
    end
end

#Main Program
while continue
    get_input()
    tokenize($input).to_s + "\n" #Ignore these three methods
    scramble_sentence($input)
    ask_again()                  #This is the method I am referring to.
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`continue` is a local variable. When you put it in a method, it is no longer accessible from the "main program". The simplest solution to this is to make `ask_again` return either true or false, and set `continue` to whatever `ask_again` returns:

```
#Main Program
continue = true
while continue
    get_input()
    tokenize($input).to_s + "\n" #Ignore these three methods
    scramble_sentence($input)
    continue = ask_again                  #This is the method I am referring to.
end
```

More advice: Generally it's not a good idea to use global variables like you seem to be with `$input`. It's probably better to let `get_input` and `tokenize` return strings instead of making them modify the global variable `$input`. Here's how my "main program" would probably look if I were writing it:

```
loop do
    tokenized_input = tokenize(get_input).to_s + "\n"
    scramble_sentence(tokenized_input)
    break unless ask_again
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to set a variable to the value that a method returns! I didn't think of this.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point. That part wasn't in the OP's question so I guess I forgot it in my answer as well. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

or you could make `continue` an instance variable (`@continue`) and add

```
@continue = true
```

before

```
while @continue
```

but better to have `ask_again` return t/f.